# Remove folders with rmdir in PHP

Tags: php, directory, rmdir

I have a txt file where I list some folders I want to remove from the server (separated by comma).

**The txt file contains for example:**

folder1,folder1/folder2,folder1/folder2/folder3

I am trying to use rmdir to remove all the folders. The problem is that rmdir wont remove the folders if there are any folders within, and the txt file sadly list the folders in the wrong order.

Any solution? (the folders will not contain any files)

**Here is the code:**

```
$text_file = "folders.txt";

$all_folders_separated_by_comma = file_get_contents($text_file);

function not_empty_string($s) { return $s !== ""; }

$separate_all_folders = array_filter(explode(',', $all_folders_separated_by_comma), 'not_empty_string');

foreach ($separate_all_folders as $folder) {
rmdir($folder);
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [A recursive remove directory function for PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1407338/a-recursive-remove-directory-function-for-php)

Comment: There are many other dupes of this on SO. Just check the "Related" sidebar on the right and take your pick.

Comment: If it's all just (nested) folders, not files in the folders itself, you could just `rsort($separate_all_folders);`

Comment: Thanks Jon, for the sidebar tip. Found the solution on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1833518/remove-empty-subfolders-with-php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way would be to reverse sort the folder array
[rsort](http://ca.php.net/manual/en/function.rsort.php) to fix the ordering. Then check that the filename is indeed a folder with [is_dir](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-dir.php).

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Ended up using the first answer on: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1833518/remove-empty-subfolders-with-php