# Laravel 4 clear all expired cache

Tags: php, caching, laravel-4

In Laravel, we can store cache with this:

```
Cache::put($dynamickey, 'value', $minutes);
```

But this will end up more and more cache files stored even after it is expired. If we try to clean it with `php artisan cache:clear` or `Cache::flush();`, it will wipe out all the cache including those that are still valid.

Is it possible to have auto clean up that will clear only expired cache? Thanks.

Comment: You should consider something like memcached or redis for that.

Comment: Why don't you just let it expire? The files will get deleted afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

```
$value = Cache::remember('users', function()
{
    return DB::table('users')->get();
});
```

Does the work. It validate if cache with given key exists and returns its value. It it does not exist or expired then refresh given cache key with new value.

For Images cache I uses logic like:

1. tore image md5($file); //where $file === full image path with
   image name
2. Store image md5(file_get_contents($file)); //self explaining method :)
3. Then

   if (Cache::has($cacheKey_name) && !Cache::has($cacheKey_content))
   {
       Cache::forget($cacheKey_name);
       Cache::forget($cacheKey_content);
   }

It will check if image is cached and only content changed. If yes then remove old cache and cache new image (with new content). With this logic you will have always fresh image content (with overwritten images).

Or, you can always create artisan task and create Controller to check all cache data in storage directory, then create Cron Task.

Answer (score 0):

you can create an function like this

```
function cache($key,$value,$min){

    (Cache::has($key))?Cache::put($key,$value,$min):Cache::add($key,$value,$min);


if(Cache::has('caches')){
    $cache=Cache::get('caches');
    $cache[time()+(60*$min)]=$key;
    Cache::forget('caches');
    Cache::rememberForever('caches',function() use($cache){
        return $cache;
    });
}else{
    $cache[time()+(60*$min)]=$key;
    Cache::rememberForever('caches',function() use($cache){
        return $cache;
    });
}
$cache=Cache::get('caches');
foreach($cache as $key=>$value)
{
    if($key<time())
    {
        Cache::forget($value);
        array_forget($cache, $key);
    }
}
Cache::forget('caches');
Cache::rememberForever('caches',function() use($cache){
    return $cache;
});}
```

and to remove this cache empty folders you can edit

```
vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Cache\FileStore.php
```

on line 182
after this code

```
public function forget($key)
{
    $file = $this->path($key);

    if ($this->files->exists($file))
    {
        $this->files->delete($file);
```

add a function to remove all empty folders , like blow code

```
    public function forget($key)
{
    $file = $this->path($key);

    if ($this->files->exists($file))
    {
        $this->files->delete($file);
         RemoveEmptySubFolders($this->getDirectory());
```

to use this function you can see it 
[Remove empty subfolders with PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1833518/remove-empty-subfolders-with-php)